# JCO IDOC Server for multiple destinations

Tags: java, jco, idoc, sapjco3

I'm developing a IDOC server which can connect to multiple destinations on same SAP system(gateway host will be same) and receive IDocs. I'm not sure that I need multiple JCoServer instance running or single JCoServer with multiple destinations.

If latter is the case, why would there is a parameter to specify the destination name using `jco.server.repository_destination` property when providing the server data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `jco.server.repository_destination` is for telling the JCoServer which JCoDestination to use for querying required RFC meta data from the SAP system. RFC meta data is always needed for interpreting incoming RFC request data correctly.

So if your JCoServer is only for serving RFC requests which originate from the same SAP system (the same SID), then specifying `jco.server.repository_destination` is sufficient. The RFC meta data won't change regardless which RFC destination (defined in SM59) is used from this ABAP system.

But if the JCoServer is also supposed to serve RFC requests initiated from other SAP systems (from other SIDs), then the needed RFC meta data may differ and you should specify a `jco.server.repository_map` in addition. In general, RFC meta data should always be queried from the same SAP system where an RFC request originates from.

By the way, you cannot start multiple JCoServer instances with the same `jco.server.progid` for registering at the same `jco.server.gwhost` and `jco.server.gwserv`. If you try then JCo will throw some exception. You need one JCoServer instance for each progid/gwhost/gwserv combination set.

Comment: Thanks, But guess I'm using different `jco.server.progid` too.. The case is I have few destinations registered on different programs in SAP end(same gwhost) I think this should be able to handle with a single JCoServer. isn't it?

Comment: No. You need one JCoServer instance for each progid/gwhost/gwserv combination set. There is no way to specify multiple progids for one server. The progid should identify the server program to address an RFC request to. If you would like to address the same server program don't configure different progids at ABAP side. Otherwise you have to live with multiple JCoServer instances and registered connections.