# SAP JCo Server for multiple (dynamic) SAP systems and repositories

Tags: java, saprfc, jco, sapjco3

We have two SAP systems (**SYS_A** and **SYS_B**). From the **SYS_A** we want to call an RFC FM from the system **SYS_B** (an RFM, which is physically on the **SYS_B** system, so JCo Server repository should also point to **SYS_B** repository) with the destination parameter defined as JCo Server, for example on system **SYS_A** we call using ABAP:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'RFC_SYS_B'
  DESTINATION 'JCO_SERVER'.
```

So how to define the properties of the server and repository in JCo in such way, that we get dynamically metadata about the called function? And how to do it dynamically, so that when call an RFC FM from another system **SYS_C** it will also work, i.e JCo Server will also catch this call along with the call metadata?

Should we use property `jco.server.repository_map` for this? If so, how do you define it using this parameter? How to define it in JCo, that calls are coming from **SYS_A**, but the repositories are on **SYS_A** and **SYS_B** and maybe on any another system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing different destinations in applications on the Tomcat server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46280376/implementing-different-destinations-in-applications-on-the-tomcat-server)

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: it is about the same RFC function on all three systems?

Comment: No, we want to call from SYS_A a RFM function, which is physically stored on SYS_B (and is not on SYS_A). And the point is to dynamically change the repository in JCo depending on what system we call the functions from. For example if we call only functions that are on SYS_A, then we can define repository as `jco.server.repository_destination=SYS_A`, but how to define it to have access also to system repositories from SYS_B and SYS_C when we want to call the functions stored on these systems? Should we use `jco.server.repository_map`? Or maybe we can do it in any different way?:)

Comment: Yes, you need map, [JCO IDOC Server for multiple destinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117962/jco-idoc-server-for-multiple-destinations)

Comment: Ok, thanks thank you for confirmation. 
I see documentation of `JCO_REP_MAP` ([link](https://www.int13h.nl:8443/_content/SAPDocuments/JCo_API_3_0/index.html?index-all.html)), but how should I exactly use `jco.server.repository_map`? When I am calling from SYS_A (client 100) a RFM stored on SYS_B (on client 200), than I should use it in such way:  `jco.server.repository_destination=SYS_A
jco.server.repository_map=SYS_A(100)=SYS_A;SYS_B(200)=SYS_B` ? But how to define this additional destination for SYS_B?